# Convert all the number, Exclude a particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can convert all the number in a HTML markup to persian number, But I want to exclude a particular class from the convert number.

I changed code as following but it does not work.

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/o87bdzba/

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
persian={0:'۰',1:'۱',2:'۲',3:'۳',4:'۴',5:'۵',6:'۶',7:'۷',8:'۸',9:'۹'};
 function traverse(el){
  if(el.nodeType==3){
   var list=el.data.match(/[0-9]/g);
   if(list!=null && list.length!=0){
    for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
     el.data=el.data.replace(list[i],persian[list[i]]);
   }
  }
  for(var i=0;i<el.childNodes.length;i++){
   traverse(el.childNodes[i]);
  }
 }
    //traverse(document.body.not('.dont_convert')); ** this 
traverse(document.body);
```

```html
November <span class"dont_convert">2016</span> Community Moderator Election RESULTS
Documentation Update, November 29th
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if element has "dont_convert" class.

```js
persian={0:'۰',1:'۱',2:'۲',3:'۳',4:'۴',5:'۵',6:'۶',7:'۷',8:'۸',9:'۹'};
function traverse(el){
  if(el.classList && el.classList.contains('dont_convert')){
    return;
  }
  if(el.nodeType==3){
    var list=el.data.match(/[0-9]/g);
    if (list != null && list.length != 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
      el.data = el.data.replace(list[i], persian[list[i]]);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
    traverse(el.childNodes[i]);
  }
}

traverse(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
November <span class="dont_convert">2016</span> Community Moderator Election RESULTS Documentation Update, November 29th
```

UPDATE: JQuery version

```js
persian={0:'۰',1:'۱',2:'۲',3:'۳',4:'۴',5:'۵',6:'۶',7:'۷',8:'۸',9:'۹'};
function traverse(el){
  if($(el).hasClass('dont_convert')){
    return;
  }
  if(el.nodeType==3){
    var list=el.data.match(/[0-9]/g);
    if (list != null && list.length != 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
      el.data = el.data.replace(list[i], persian[list[i]]);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
    traverse(el.childNodes[i]);
  }
}

traverse(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
November <span class="dont_convert">2016</span> Community Moderator Election RESULTS Documentation Update, November 29th
```

Comment: interesting. it seems it works. maybe your browser is old ?

Comment: @Mehdi jquery version is added. try that, it will probably work with your browser